# Comparing class to Interface it inherits ( via Foo is IBar ) returns false : Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, types, comparison

### What I am trying to accomplish

I want to be able to bind an event handler from one class to the `Click` event of a button of an object in another class in the XAML of that control :

For Example :

```
<Button Click="{OtherClass.EventHandler}"/>
```

### My Approach

I'm working from code that is nearly a decade old taken from [here](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/09/hooking-up-commands-to-events-in-wpf.html)

I'm working with a class that inherits the `System.Windows.Input.ICommand` interface which basically wraps an `Action` to make my life less... stupid :

```
public class Command : ICommand {
    private Action _ToExecute;
    public Action ToExecute{
        get{ return this._ToExecute; }
        set{ this._ToExecute = value; }
    }

    public Command( Action ToExecute ){ this._ToExecute = ToExecute; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged; //Never Used
    public bool CanExecute( object parameter ){ return true; }
    public void Execute( object parameter ){
        this._ToExecute?.Invoke( );
    }
}
```

I make use of this class within the following class which extends the behavior of Buttons to be able to allow me to tie the `Click` event handler of buttons to these commands :

```
public static class ButtonClickBehavior{
    public static ReadOnly DependencyProperty[] Properties = 
        EventBehviourFactory.CreateCommandExecutionEventBehaviour(
            ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new string[]{ "Command", "Parameter" },
            typeof( ButtonClickBehavior ) );

    public static void SetCommand( DependencyObject o, ICommand value ){
        o.SetValue( Properties[ 0 ], value );
    }

    public static ICommand GetCommand( DependencyObject o ){
        return o.GetValue( Properties[ 0 ] as ICommand;
    }

    public static void SetParameter( DependencyObject o, object value ){
        o.SetValue( Properties[ 1 ], value );
    }

    public static object GetParameter( DependencyObject o ){
        return o.GetValue( Properties[ 1 ] );
    }
}
```

This class makes use of the aforementioned static class : ( based heavily on code ripped wholesale from the source cited above )

```
public static class EventBehaviorFactory {
    public static DependencyProperty[] CreateCommandExecutionEventBehaviour(
        RoutedEvent routedEvent, string[] propertyNames, Type ownerType ){
        ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour
            CommandExecutor = new ExecuteCommandOunRoutedBehavior( routedEvent );

        DependencyProperty p = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            propertyNames[ 0 ], typeof( ICommand ), ownerType,
            new PropertyMetadata( null, CommandExecutor.PropertyChanged ) );

        if ( propertyNames.Count( ) > 1 )
            return new DependencyProperty[ ]{
                p, DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                       propertyNames[ 1 ], typeof( ICommand ), ownerType,
                       new PropertyMetadata( null, CommandExecutor.PropertyChanged ) )
            };
        else return new DependencyProperty[ ] { p };
    }

    private class ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour : ExecuteCommandBehaviour {
        private readonly RoutedEvent _routedEvent;
        public ExecuteCommandOnRoutedEventBehaviour( RoutedEvent routedEvent ){
            this._routedEvent = routedEvent;
        }
        protected override void AdjustEventHandlers(
            DependencyObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue ){
            UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
            if ( oldValue != null )
                element.RemoveHandler(
                    _routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( EventHandler );
            if ( newValue != null )
                element.AddHandler(
                    _routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler( EventHandler );

        }

        protected void EventHandler( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ){
            HandleEvent( sender, e );
        }
    }

    internal abstract class ExecuteCommandBehaviour{
        protected DependencyProperty
            _commandProperty, _paramProperty;
        protected abstract void AdjustEventHandler(
            DependencyObject sender, object oldValue, object newValue );

        protected void HandleEvent( object sender, EventArgs e ){
            DependencyObject dp = sender as DependencyObject;
            if ( dp == null )
                return;

            ICommand cmd = dp.GetValue( _commandProperty ) as ICommand;
            if ( command == null )
                return;

            object param
            if ( this._paramProperty == null || ( 
                 param = dp.GetValue( this._paramProperty ) ) == null ){
                if ( cmd.CanExecute( e ) )
                    cmd.Execute( e );
            } else {
                if ( cmd.CanExecute( param ) )
                    cmd.Execute( param );
            }
        }

        public void PropertyChanged(
            DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e ) {
            /*THIS IS THE LINE GIVING ME TROUBLE.*/
            if ( e.Property.PropertyType is ICommand ){
                //DO STUFF
            } else if ( /*Something ELSE*/ )
                //DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
    }
}
```

I realize the code I am using comes from a source that is nearly a decade old and there should exist something somewhere that should be able to do what I want but for all my google searches I came up empty ( except for that I kept hitting this result so I figured whatever, I'll modify it to fit my needs and roll with it ). If someone has a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, I am all for it ( again, I would like to be able to do the actual binding in XAML, ***NOT in the code behind*** )

### My Problem

The problem is that my type comparison fails ( even when I watch the debug I see the PropertyType is of type ICommand ). The PropertyType compared to ICommand always returns false when I use the `is` keyword, and any attempts at Linq sorcery ( such as `e.Property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces( ).Any( i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition( ) == typeof( ICommand ) )` ) fail as well.

So if someone has a better approach I'm all ears, but for now - why is my type comparison failing so hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.PropertyType` is `Type`, not an instance of that type, so comparision with "is" will not work. What you need is (for example):

```
typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(e.Property.PropertyType)
```

Comment: Of course. I always screw that up - comparing a type when I mean to be comparing a class instance... but I didn't know about that IsAssignableFrom. This worked perfectly - thanks.